# asyncio.TimeoutError due to asyncio.wait_for in async_generator deplete or consume the async_generator

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, openai-api

I have and async generator, I want to wait for the next element 1 second, if the next element is not ready in this amount of time I want to print a waiting message and wait another second. I'm using the `asyncio.wait_for` in order to wait for the next element, but the problem is that when the first timeout fail and it returns again to the `asyncio.wait_for` I'm getting an `asyncio.StopAsyncIteration` error, so the first exception deplete or consume the generator and I can't wait again.

Here you have an example code:

```
import openai
import asyncio
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

def streaming_chat(history):
  response = openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(
      model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages=history,
      stream=True
  )
  return response

history = \
  [
    {'role': 'user', 'content': "Can you give me three tips about cooking"}
  ]

response_async_generator = await streaming_chat(history=history)
print(type(response))

final_message = False

while True:
    try:
        next_element = await asyncio.wait_for(response_async_generator.__anext__(), timeout=0.01)
        print(next_element)

    except asyncio.TimeoutError as to_err:
        print("Waiting...")
    except asyncio.StopAsyncIteration as err:
        print("Failed")
        break
```

I expect to be able to wait for the next element without consume the generator. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What happens if you change `response_async_generator = await streaming_chat(history=history)` to `response_async_generator = streaming_chat(history=history)`?

Comment: Not tried because I'm not on my computer now but probably an error saying async function never awaited